# In Corda, can you create more than one transaction in a single flow?

Tags: corda

All the Corda flows I've seen have only involved the creation, signing and finalisation of a single transaction. Is it possible to create, sign and finalise multiple transactions in a single flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A flow can create zero, one or multiple transactions.

You can even use looping constructs within a flow to create multiple transactions:

```
while (cash > 0) {
    createCashTransaction(5.DOLLARS)
    cash -= 5.DOLLARS
}
```

Or use conditional logic to decide whether or not to create a transaction:

```
if (cash > 0) {
    createCashTransaction(5.DOLLARS)
}
```